# Migration-Upgrade of TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 - How To Guide Required

Tags: sql-server, tfs, azure-devops, migration

I have a client requirement to upgrade the existing TFS (Azure DevOps Server) 2010 instance as follows:

1. Upgrade TFS 2010 to TFS 2013
2. Upgrade TFS 2013 to TFS 2019
3. Migrate TFS 2019 to Azure DevOps Services (using the Data Migration Tool)

**The immediate focus for now is only on the first upgrade and so the final two migrations can be ignored for now.**

Our entire TFS implementation (application and data tiers) is hosted on a single server - Windows Server 2008 R2 **Enterprise**. This server also runs a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance for the TFS databases.

For the TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 upgrade, we intend to use the following hardware:

1. A separate dedicated server for the application tier - Windows Server 2012 (**Enterprise** I guess)
2. A separate, dedicated server for the data tier - SQL Server 2012 or 2014

As this is going to be a Migration-Upgrade as opposed to an In-Place upgrade, is there a reliable or good set of instructions and/or document that I could refer to get me over the line successfully for this activity?

Comment: Google? https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=vsarupgradeguide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/pre-production?view=azure-devops

Comment: @DanielMann, you're absolutely right Google is always a good place to start. Problem is, a Google query will return so many different articles written on identical scenarios, I like to take a more cautious approach by seeking expert opinion rather than take a random gamble on any of the Googled solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The general process for upgrading an existing deployment of Team Foundation Server is to:

- Prepare your environment. Such as upgrade your SQL sever (required),
  operating system...
- Expect the best, prepare for the worst. The single most important
  step you can take here is to ensure you have a complete and
  consistent set of database backups. Note:Detach collection before your back up
- Do the upgrade! Restore SQL database from #2 Attach collection
- Configure new features.

For a more detail progress, you could take a look at our official tutorial here-- [Upgrade from TFS 2005 to TFS 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/tfs-2005-to-2015?view=tfs-2013) Same for TFS2010~ TFS2013.

Besides, since you have used different hardware during the upgrade, you could also pay attention to the notice in this doc-- [TFS Application Tier will use different hardware than it’s using right now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/upgrade-2013/new-app-tier-hardware?view=tfs-2013)

Comment: @hitman126 Also in you migrated hardware, make sure you use the minimum OS and SQL for 2019 since you don't want yet another VM to move 2013 to 2019.  So your intermediate environment should be OS 2012 (min) and SQL 2014 that you will unfortunately need to upgrade also to 2016 (min) for Azure DevOps 2019.

Comment: @PatrickLu, thanks for your feedback. Most appreciated. Regarding the detaching and reattaching of the collection database for a migration upgrade, I got the impression from the feedback received on another thread started by [Janiv Ratson](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/75339373-c729-4d09-853c-ab83ae45439c/migrating-from-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2013?forum=tfsintegration), that it was only applicable if the source and target environments were running identical hardware. Is that not the case?

Comment: @Etienne, appreciate your feedback. Just to clarify, as TFS 2013 does support Windows Server 2012 and likewise TFS 2019 which is the final upgrade on the roadmap, the view from here is to use Windows Server 2012 for both upgrades, just to keep things simple and consistent across the two product versions. I hope this can be clarified but I don't think there's a particular need to upgrade the OS to 2016........or is there? But of course, if it is imperative that we upgrade the OS to 2016 then we'll definitely look to go down that route for the TFS 2019 upgrade.

Comment: Another key point to add to our migration scenario is that we intend to perform a dry-run of the migration upgrade to the new app and data tier servers, just to give us some time to carry out the necessary sanity check and validation. As such, we are going to be running two instances of TFS 2013 simultaneously - one in Production and the other being the Dry Run. What are the additional steps to ensure both instances are kept discrete and that we can avoid any corruption or the data integrity being compromised?

Comment: Also, just to add, we're not migrating any SharePoint or Reporting Services items by the way. All we're migrating are strictly source files.

Comment: @hitman126 For system requirements, just as Etienne pointed out you could use minimum OS version and SQL version. You are able to use OS 2012 as minimum, however .I think he is talking about SQL version 2016. For Azure devops 2019, you need to use SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1) as the minimum SQL version.  You could find detail info in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops

Comment: Yes directly detach attach collection database only running identical hardware. For environment you need some extra steps. I found  a  more detail official tutorial, you could refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=azure-devops .  For dry run. I am not sure if this is available on TFS 2010. It's quiet an old product(10 years) But if you want run two instances of TFS 2013 simultaneously. Please make sure you have changed Server IDs. If more than one database has the same GUID, your deployment can become unstable or unusable.

Comment: How to change server ID, you could refer this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019#changeserverid

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, apologies. My bad. Yes Etienne is definitely right about SQL 2016 being the minimum spec for TFS 2019. Somehow, I got it mixed up with the TFS 2015 upgrade.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, regarding the dry-run proposal I wasn't entirely clear on bits of what you stated, but perhaps that's because I wasn't very clear on what I'm lining up. Basically, because I wish to minimise the risk of opting for a "Big Bang" upgrade, I'd like to have the TFS 2010 instance in Production still running after the migration, while we sanity check the upgraded TFS 2013 instance. Essentially, the dry-run is simply to allow us perform the sanity check on TFS 2013, identify and address any issues before performing a final upgrade. I guess the server ID will still require changing?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, cheers for the "official tutorial" link. What I'm slightly confused though is where it says under **Install and configure SQL Server on the new data-tier server** that: <br>"You must install the same version and edition that you used previously, including service pack and cumulative update levels"<br> We're looking to upgrade from TFS 2010 (with SQL Server 2008 R2) to TFS 2013 which only supports SQL Server 2012 and later.<br>Does the statement  **You must install the same version and edition that you used previously....** mean we can't migrate from SQL Server 2008 to 2012?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT, having re-read the article and a few other ones regarding the database upgrade, this is how I've interpreted the information given. Kindly confirm if accurate.  1) Obtain SQL Server 2008 R2 database backups for our current TFS 2010 instance  2) Provision the new (target) server and install the same version and edition of SQL Server, i.e. 2008 R2.  3) Restore the database backups from the first step to the new server. 4) Upgrade SQL on the new server to the 2012 edition which is the version that will be required for TFS 2013.  5) Finally, install and configure the app tier.

Comment: Hi @hitman126.  You can install SQL 2014 for TFS 2013 (the requirement is that you move from standard to standard or enterprise to enterprise not the same version).  Then like Patrick mention, detach the collection in TFS management console, backup and move to the new 2012OS/2014SQL machine.  Restore.  Then you can reattach in TFS and it will upgrade.  Do change the Server ID after to prevent clashes.

Comment: Then you can upgrade the SQL server to 2016 and upgrade inplace to Azure DevOps 2019.  You can go from Enterprise to Standard with SQL but you'll need to uncompress the db before you do if it was turned on in 2010.

Comment: @Etienne, excellent!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it,

You need to upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 first then to Azure DevOps Server 2019 and finally to the cloud with the migration tool.

In order to migrate to TFS 2013, you need a minimum of Windows Server 2012 and SQL 2014.  You first detach the TFS 2010 collection and take a backup of your 2010 db.  You need to migration from SQL Standard to SQL Standard but you can go from 2008 to 2014.  You can also go from Enterprise to Standard but you need to make sure you db is not compressed in 2008.  If it is you'll need to uncompress it first before you take a backup.  You can do this like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2712111/disabling-sql-server-data-compression-in-tfs-databases) after you install TFS 2013 (you don't need to have the db there to do that, you can install but not create a defaultcollection) restore the db and attach it from the TFS management console.  It will upgrade automatically.

Then to migrate to Azure DevOps 2019, you need a minimum of Windows Server 2012 (so no need to change VM) but you'll need to upgrade to SQL 2016 SP1 which is the minimum for AzDo 2019.  You just need to run the installation of AzDo 2019 and it will upgrade 2013 to 2019 inplace.

In order to make sure you don't have clash, make sure you change the Server SID in TFS 2013 with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd?view=azure-devops-2019#changeserverid),

In AzDo 2019, do a non-production upgrade and it will take care of that for you.

Finally once you upgraded to 2019 (in-place) you can run the migration wizard and go to the cloud

All the requirements are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops)

Comment: That's wonderful @Etienne. Thoroughly appreciate this. Just got a couple of points I'd like to clarify though, just so I have it all crystal clear. So firstly, are you saying it's perfectly okay to obtain my TFS 2010 backups from SQL Server 2008 R2 and restore them to the new data tier server which is running SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014? Secondly, for my backups, I was looking to rely on some nightly backups taken via a backup plan I've created in the TFS 2010 Admin console. Between these and the manual backups taken in SQL Server Management Studio, is there a preference?

Comment: Yes you can restore from 2008 R2 to 2012/2014 but just make sure you have detached the collection in TFS (you can reattach after) BEFORE you take the backup. You can then just restore and reattach from TFS management studio and upgrade. In fact you can take a backup of only you main collection you don't need the configuration database OR you can take the full backup from the TFS admin console (I didn't remember it offered backups ;-)) and restore the whole set.  THEN you need to configure your TFS 2013 after the db restore.

Comment: aren't we muddying the waters a little bit now with all this mention of detaching and reattaching the project database? I thought that scenario's been confirmed as only being applicable when migrating to identical hardware, which is not the case in our scenario. We're migrating to completely new hardware, as the current Windows Server 2008 cannot support the migration to TFS 2013. Just to clarify, my approach is to initially backup the project database via the TFS 2010 Power Tools and then using the TFS 2013 upgrade wizard, restore them to the new server to complete the installation

Comment: I don't think that will work, I think the old TFS 2010 backup tool can only restore to same hardware/sql.  Your best bet is the detach the collection in the TFS admin console back it up, restore to the the new SQL (2012/2014) with the regular SQL backup/restore tool and then in the new TFS 2013 admin console reattach, this will trigger and upgrade.  This way you don't need the configuration db, the reporting db, the analysis db.  If you don't do that, it's much more complex.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback @Etienne. Good news is that I also looked into Mohamed Radwan's tutuorial which is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nm-WOLc-GQQ&list=PL23zsTbJ1mNoEWSCGLLcTaLXIIkXh6SfB&index=9) and it does the job perfectly, using the TFS 2013 TFSBackup and TFSRestore utilities and my first dry-run so far has gone great. Mohamed upgrades from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 in his tutorial but I understand that the process is equally valid for a TFS 2010 to TFS 2013 upgrade. I plan another dry-run to verify and validate further, but I'm definitely inclined to go with that approach

Comment: Go with what works for you and your organization @hitman126!

Comment: you make some really interesting points which I'd love to understand better, if I may. Regarding the detach and attach approach, what happens to the Tfs_Configuration and other databases once the team project collection has been detached from the TFS 2010 instance and attached to the TFS 2013 instance on our new hardware? Do those databases get recreated as part of the upgrade? Also, what's your assessment of the aforementioned YouTube tutorial by Mohamed Radwan for a TFS 2010 migration upgrade to TFS 2012 and are there any flaws or shortcomings you see with that approach please?

Comment: Mohamed's video is good and you should follow it.  As for my approach I usually do this because I like to control my target and what's installed on it.  Sometimes it means not installing RS or SharePoint or upgrading components, etc.  So I like to just detach collection and backup then restore and reattach + upgrade.  I've done hundreds of those so I go with what I know.